# Eclipse won't compile, bad class file, wrong version

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to compile code checked out of SVN from another developer.  Eclipse has been giving me a lot of trouble lately.

Here are my project-specific settings:
[image]

This is what the compile section of my ant file:

```
<target name="compile" depends="build-common, init" description="Compile files. ">
    <javac srcdir="${src_dir}" destdir="${build_dir}" debug="true" >
        <classpath path="${tomcat_home}/lib/servlet-api.jar;" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

When I compile ( using Ant ) I get an error message:

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to H:\MYCOMPANY\portlets\build
    [javac] H:\MYCOMPANY\portlets\src\com\mycompany\portlets\CourseList.java:3: cannot access java.io.IOException
    [javac] bad class file: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\lib\rt.jar(java/io/IOException.class)
    [javac] class file has wrong version 49.0, should be 48.0
    [javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
    [javac] import java.io.IOException;
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] 1 error
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class file version of 49.0 belongs to Java 1.5.x, whereas the one of 48.0 belongs to one of the Java 1.4.x version. The classfile structure had changed in 1.5 due to the introduction of several new features and changes made in the Java Language Specification.

From the error, one can deduce that a Java 1.4 classfile was expected, whereas a Java 1.5 classfile was found. It appears that the compiler is a Java 1.4 compiler, so you should attempt to verify whether you're using the right version of the Java compiler and also the right JDK (i.e. JDK home).

**ADDENDUM**

Ant tends to look for the javac executable in the $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac . If the JAVA_HOME environment variable has been set incorrectly, say to a Java 1.4 home, then there is a likelihood of getting the described error even in Eclipse.

**ADDENDUM #2**

The addition of entries to the PATH environment variable *could result* in altering the search classpath behavior of Ant, possibly resulting in a different tools.jar being used for the purpose of compiling the sources. This might be due to the jvm.dll from the JRE 1.4.2 installation being used to run Eclipse (and hence Ant).

Comment: How do I check the Ant compiler version?

Comment: Well, by default this tends to be the version of compiler in the JDK home (the Eclipse launch configuration can help identify the home). You could specify a different compiler using the executable attribute of the javac Ant task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Comment: I don't understand, I am using Java 1.6 JDK.  I added a screenshot to my post.  Why should that matter?

Comment: You're using JDK 1.6 to call ant, but the compiler is called by ant in a new process which may use a different JDK

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set correctly to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07  however, Oracle Dev Suite has added some jre 1.4 values to my PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

> bad class file: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\lib\rt.jar(java/io/IOException.class)
>   class file has wrong version 49.0, should be 48.0

It is telling that the mentioned class file is been compiled using a compiler which generates class files of version 49.0, while ant expects it to be compiled using a compiler which generates class files of version 48.0. Since the class in question is part of the JRE, you need to update the classpath in your `build.xml` to include the JRE containing class files of version 48.0.

Comment: Umm, Java 6 has classfile version of 50.0.

Comment: @Vineet: Hmm, you're right. I was just translating from the error message. But that doesn't explain why `IOException.class` in JRE 1.6 has version 49.0 as stated in the error message? Anyway, I generified my answer to remove the specific JRE versions.

Comment: Hmm, interesting...I checked classes in both the 1.5 and 1.6 JRE `rt.jar` (including ones that were specifically updated in 1.6) and they all have version 49. I wonder what the purpose in that is..

Answer (score 3):

First of all your project settings have nothing to do with your build script. Project settings tell you how Eclipse builds your project, not how your ant file will run.

To find under which jvm ant runs, right-mouse click your build script in Eclipse and choose "Run as...". In the popup dialog navigate to jvm tab and check which jre is used to run your script.

Comment: This helped a little.  There is no JVM tab, but the JRE tab does correctly use jre1.6.0_07.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have Eclipse opened and gave wrong tab name. Well, next I would check:


1. If you have jre 1.4 installed anywhere.
2. If you have JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME defined, and if yes where they point to.
3. Run java -version from command line to see which java your path points to. If it is 1.4, adjust your path environment to point to 1.6.

Answer (score 3):

The error message means that the compiler tool included in tool.jar your Ant is using is of older version than the class it attempts to compile.
Message "[javac] class file has wrong version 50.0 should be 49.0" would mean that your class file needs jdk 6.0 but your tool.jar comes from jdk 5.0 distribution. To switch to correct tools.jar in eclipse open Window>Preferences>Ant>Runtime>Global Entries.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running Ant with a version 1.5 java compiler but compiling against the class libraries (rt.jar) of a 1.6 installation. You should set up your build.xml so that it will consistently use both (the compiler and the class libraries) of the the same java version.

Comment: This might be the problem, where do I specify that?  In the ant build, should I add target="1.5" source="1.5" to the compile command?

Comment: It's in your "External Tools Configurations", i.e. per ant launcher. Especially check the JRE and Classpath tabs. The problem is is probably in the JRE setting, but you may have manually added a different version of the rt.jar to the Classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to copy `tools.jar` from `jdk/jre` to `common/lib` of tomcat.

It worked for me as demonstrated [here](http://programargoogleando.blogspot.com/2011/04/class-file-has-wrong-version-500-should.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Java Version for ANT also because If you are using your Run Time Environment as JDK1.8 then Your ANT should be also point to same version or Ant should refer tools.jar file from JDK1.8/lib/tools.jar location.
To fix this issue i your Eclipse Go to  Window --> Preference --> Ant -->Runtime -->Global Entries . Here check and update tools.jar path with latest version as below.:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\tools.jar

Then run your build script issue will be resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the tools.jar in eclipse to the correct version fixed it.
I was using jre 1.6 and had to change it to use 1.8 to get the class file in version 52.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use JDK JRE which is located at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre, not public